# List of Java social network engine (framework/platform)

Tags: java, social-networking

There are lots of social engine based on PHP like SocialEngine and Boonex Dolphin, however I can't find one built from Java language. Is there any?

What I can find are just CMS, like Alfresco which is made with Java technology.

Comment: What is a social network engine? I understood alfresco was a CMS - a regular content management system. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems) for some CMS for Java

Comment: Maybe he wants to benefit from the advantages of Java...

Comment: @HansWesterbeek well you're right. However, I mean like SocialEngine or Boonex (which are based on PHP)

Comment: Does any social network engine written on Java since that time? Liferay Social Office is corporate portal, not social network.

Comment: @chro I am not aware of such thing either, and yes I believe is more of a corporate portal.

Comment: As It turns out The question is actually very reasonable ! and I am up voting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with social network engine.

If you want to host your own community try something like [liferay](http://www.liferay.com). It has wikis, blogs, forums, etc.. You can integrate your own applications with it.

If you just want to connect to social services and integrate them into your application check [spring-social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social).

Comment: I mean like a social network platform

Comment: there have to be others out there?